# "Show" is working, "hide" is not. Javascript

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have the following JS script for a show/hide toggle. I kinda have to keep it  in this format because the elements it works on are a lot and formatted badly and it would be too much of a hassle to make it in jQuery.

As the title says, the "show" event is working while the "hide" is not. And since I'm a complete JS noob I was wondering it you could help me. Here's the code:

```
function toggle(obj) {
  for (var  i = 0; i< 50; i++) {
    var name = 'q' + i;
    var inchide_obj=document.getElementById(obj);
    if (inchide_obj && inchide_obj.style && inchide_obj.style.display == "block") {
      inchide_obj.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  var deschide_obj=document.getElementById(obj);
  if (deschide_obj && deschide_obj.style) {
    deschide_obj.style.display = "block";
    deschide_obj.focus();
  }
}
```

The html implies some blocks of texts each with its own class, q1, q2, etc. Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: *"too much of a hassle to make it in jQuery"* I doubt that.

Comment: Did you test it in all browsers? Bear in mind that not all native javascript functions are working or the same implementation to all browsers that's why if you are developing an application that you dont worry about browser compatibility use "jQuery"

Comment: @JobertEnamno Advocating for jQuery for such simple things is a bit of an overkill, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code first tries to hide the element 50 times, and eventually shows it at the end, unconditionally. I believe you're looking for this:

```
function toggle(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj && obj.style) {
        if(obj.style.display != "block") {
            obj.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            obj.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```